# QML-Maps-Qt, tap the screen with a map, processing and obtain the coordinates

Tags: android, qt, location, maps, qml

I'm making a project with the support of maps on Qt Creator (Community) 5.5.1 for Android. I used QML and now I need some help, because I don't know what I will do further.

First, I determined my location in QML and connected maps. QML-code is here:
main.qml:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtPositioning 5.3
import QtLocation 5.3
Item {
      PositionSource{
          active: true
          onPositionChanged:{
              console.log(position.coordinate);
          }
      }
      Map{
          id: map
          anchors.fill: parent
          plugin: Plugin {name: "osm"}
          center: QtPositioning.coordinate(44.561083, 33.530209)
          zoomLevel: 14
      }
}
```

And code of main.cpp:

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("main.qml"));
    view.setResizeMode(QQuickView::SizeRootObjectToView);

    view.resize(300, 400);
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

Project is building and running on the Desktop, it's working and maps are showed on the screen. But on the Armeabi (android) they aren't showed. I was testing my programm on the real device. [My device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yUkZ.png) [Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSvSk.jpg)Yes, it's running and building, but screen is white and there are some red logs:

> E/Zygote  (23941): Zygote:  error closing descriptor E/Zygote 
>   (23941): libcore.io.ErrnoException: close failed: EBADF (Bad file
>   number) E/Zygote  (23941):    at libcore.io.Posix.close(Native Method)
>   E/Zygote  (23941):    at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.close(BlockGuardOs.java:75) E/Zygote  (23941):
>     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.closeServerSocket(ZygoteInit.java:224)
>   E/Zygote  (23941):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.handleChildProc(ZygoteConnection.java:879)
>   E/Zygote  (23941):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteConnection.runOnce(ZygoteConnection.java:242)
>   E/Zygote  (23941):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.runSelectLoop(ZygoteInit.java:704)
>   E/Zygote  (23941):    at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) E/Zygote 
>   (23941):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>
> E/        (23941): appName=org.qtproject.example.LOCATIONQML,
>   acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/        (23941): 0
>
> W/libLOCATIONQML.so(23941):
>   file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.LOCATIONQML/files/main.qml:-1
>   ((null)):
>   file:///data/data/org.qtproject.example.LOCATIONQML/files/main.qml:
>   File not found E/        (23941):
>   appName=org.qtproject.example.LOCATIONQML,
>   acAppName=/system/bin/surfaceflinger E/        (23941): 0
>
> W/ResourceType(23941): No package identifier when getting name for
>   resource number 0x00000001

I have two questions:

1. What I must do for working my programm on real device Android, that maps will be shown on screen of smartphone?
2. How to do like I tap the screen of smartphone with maps and coordinates of this area are memorized? To further I could compare the user's current location and the location of the point that was clicked on maps screen ?

Comment: post a self contained example. This is likely a packaging problem of some sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your qml works fine using the latest Qt.

Try to use the standard main() that qt creator generates for you, using QQmlApplicationEngine instead of QQuickView.